# React native navigate throwing error 'Can not read property 'navigate' of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am running a code that displays menu of various dishes where users can press one of the dishes they will be taken to "Dishdetail" screen where read about the dish. The problem is when we get to the point where we click the app is using navigate but the app is throwing some error message that says the "**TypeError: Can not read Property 'navigate' of undefined**". You can see the code I have it declared in the code below.

MainComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react' ;
import Menu from './MenuComponent' ;
import { View, Image, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Text,Platform } from 'react-native'

//import { Platform } from '@unimodules/core';
import  Home  from './HomeComponent';
import Dishdetail from './DishdetailComponent' ;
import Contact from './ContactComponent' ;
import About from './AboutComponent';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator,SafeAreaView,DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation';


//1. ActionCreators import
import { fetchDishes, fetchComments, fetchPromos, fetchLeaders} from '../redux/ActionCreators';

//1.import to connect to redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';

//2.leaders state from store
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        
    } 
}

//2. get the actions creators
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
     fetchDishes:  () => {dispatch(fetchDishes())},
     fetchComments:() => {dispatch(fetchComments())},
     fetchPromos:  () => {dispatch(fetchPromos())},
     fetchLeaders: () => {dispatch(fetchLeaders())}
})

//() => <Menu/>
const MenuNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Menu: { screen: () => <Menu/>, 
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            headerLeft: <Icon name='menu' size={24}
            color='white'
            onPress={ () => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
            />
      })
    },
    Dishdetail: { screen: () => <Dishdetail/> } 
}, 
{
    initialRouteName: 'Menu',
    navigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#512DA8'
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            color: '#fff'
        }
    }
  
})

//Create stacknavigator for Home Component
const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: () => <Home/> }  
}, 
{  
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#512DA8'
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            color: '#fff'
        },
        headerLeft: <Icon name='menu' size={24}
           color='white'
           onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
        />
    }) 
});

//Create stacknavigator for Contact Component
const ContactNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Contact: { screen: () => <Contact/>}  
}, 
{  
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#512DA8'
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            color: '#fff'
        },
        headerLeft: <Icon name='menu' size={24}
          color='white'
          onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
        />
    }) 
});

//Create stacknavigator for About Component
const AboutNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    About: { screen: () => <About />}  
}, 
{  
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#512DA8'
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            color: '#fff'
        },
        headerLeft: <Icon name='menu' size={24}
          color='white'
          onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
        />
    }) 
});

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = (props) => (
     <ScrollView>
        <SafeAreaView style= {StyleSheet.container}
                forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never'}} >
                <View style={styles.drawerHeader} >
                    <View style={{flex:1}} >
                        <Image source={require('./images/logo.png')}
                            style={styles.drawerImage} />
                     </View>
                    <View style={{flex: 2}} >
                        <Text style={styles.drawerHeaderText} >Ristorante Con Fusion</Text>
                    </View> 
                </View>
                <DrawerItems   {...props } />
        </SafeAreaView>
     </ScrollView>
) 

//Create drawerNavigator for all Components
// Modified

const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: 
    {
        screen: HomeNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Home',
            drawerLabel: 'Home',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Icon 
                    name='home'
                    type='font-awesome'
                    size={24}
                    color={tintColor}
                    />
            )
        }
   },
     About:
      {
          screen: AboutNavigator,
          navigationOptions: {
              title: 'About Us',
              drawerLabel: 'About Us',
              drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                 <Icon 
                     name='info-cirlce'
                     type='font-awesome'
                     size={24}
                     color={tintColor}
                     />
             )
           }
       },
       Menu:
       {
               screen: MenuNavigator,
               navigationOptions: {
               title: 'Menu',
               drawerLabel: 'Menu',
               drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
               <Icon 
                   name='list'
                   type='font-awesome'
                   size={24}
                   color={tintColor}
                   />
               )
           }
        },
     
     Contact:
     {
         screen: ContactNavigator,
         navigationOptions: {
             title: 'Contact Us',
             drawerLabel: 'Contact Us',
             drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                 <Icon 
                     name='address-card'
                     type='font-awesome'
                     size={22}
                     color={tintColor}
                     />
             )
          }
      }
      
  },{   
     drawerBackgroundColor: '#D1C4E9',
     contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent
})


class Main extends Component {
    
    //3. Actioncreators to be loaded by componentDidMount()
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchDishes();
        this.props.fetchComments();
        this.props.fetchPromos();
        this.props.fetchLeaders();
    }

       //<Menu />:Display all dishes and when user clicks one of them
       //<Dishdetail>: filter the selectedDish and display its detail underneath
       render() {
           return (
               <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0: Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight }}>
                    <MainNavigator /> 
               </View>
           )
       }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    },
     drawerHeader:{
         backgroundColor: '#512DA8',
         height: 140,
         alignItems: 'center',
         justifyContent: 'center',
         flex: 1,
         flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    drawerHeaderText: {
         color: 'white',
         fontSize: 24,
         fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    drawerImage: {
        margin: 10,
        width: 80,
        height: 60
    }
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

MenuComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react' ;
import { FlatList } from 'react-native' ;
import { Tile } from 'react-native-elements' ;
//import { DISHES} from '../shared/dishes';


//1.import to connect to redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';

//2.leaders state from store
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
         dishes: state.dishes
         
    } 
}

//functional component
class Menu extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
           
      }
       
       //display the Menu navigation at the top
      static navigationOptions = {
            title : 'Menu'
      }
     
       
     //onPress uses the navigate to pass the dishId to Dishsetail
     //to display the dish detail of the selected dish
     render() { 
        //const  {navigate}  = this.props.navigation ;
        
        const renderMenuItem = ({item, index}) => {
            return (
                <Tile   
                    key={index}
                    title={item.name}
                    caption={item.description}
                    featured
                    onPress={() => navigate('Dishdetail', { dishId: item.id })}
                    imageSrc={{ uri: baseUrl + item.image }}
                  />
            );
        } 

       //extract the navigation comp passed to be used to pass
       //dishId to Dishdetail
       //const  { navigate }  = this.props.navigation ;

       return (
            <FlatList 
                data= {this.props.dishes.dishes}
                renderItem={renderMenuItem}
                keyExtractor={Item => Item.id.toString() }
                />
            )
     }   
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Menu);
```

DishdetailComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react' ;
import { View, Text, ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native' ;
import { Card, Icon } from 'react-native-elements' ;

//import { DISHES} from '../shared/dishes';
//import { COMMENTS } from '../shared/comments';

//1.import to connect to redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';

//2.leaders state from store
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
         dishes: state.dishes,
         comments: state.comments
    }

    
}

//functional component: Display the selectedDish name, image and 
//description using <Card> element
function RenderDish(props){
    const dish = props.dish;

    if (dish != null) {
        return (
            <Card
                featuredTitle={dish.name}
                image={{ uri: baseUrl + dish.image }}
               >
               <Text style={{margin: 10}}>
                   {dish.description}
               </Text>
               <Icon
                    raised
                    reverse
                    name={props.favorite ? 'heart' : 'heart-o'}
                    type='font-awesome'
                    color='#f50'
                    onPress={() => props.favorites ? console.log('Already favorite'): props.onPress() } 
                    />
            </Card>
        )
    }
    else {
        return (<View></View>)
    }
}

// display comments associted with dish
function RenderComments(props) {
    // pull the content out from comments array 
    const comments = props.comments;
    
    const renderCommentsItem = ({ item , index}) =>  {
      return (
        <View key={index} style={{ margin: 10}} >
           <Text style={{fonSize: 14 }}>{item.comment}</Text>
           <Text style={{fontSize: 12}}>{item.rating} Stars</Text>
           <Text style={{ fontSize: 12}}>{'--' + item.author + ',' + item.date}</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
      return (
          <Card title="Comments">
             <FlatList
             data={comments}
             renderItem={renderCommentsItem}
             keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
             />
          </Card>
      )
 
}

class Dishdetail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {          
            favorites: []
        }
    }
    
    markFavourite(dishId) {
        this.setState({favorites: this.state.favorites.concat(dishId)})

    }
    //setup the navigation for the current class [Dishdetail]
    static navigationOptions = {
        title : 'Dish Details'
    }

    render(){
        // pass or extract the dish id through the navigation
        const dishId = this.props.navigation.getParam('dishId', '');

        return (
          <ScrollView>
            <RenderDish dish={this.props.dishes.dishes[+dishId]}
              favorites={this.state.favorites.some(el => el === dishId)} 
               onPress={() => this.markFavourite(dishId)}/>

            <RenderComments comments={this.props.comments.comments.filter((comment) => comment.dishId === dishId)} />
          </ScrollView>
          )
    }
    
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dishdetail);
```